# How to persist List<Object> as jsonb in hibernate

Tags: json, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Below the Entity trying to persist :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "REQUEST")
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Request {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false)
private String code;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "CREATED_BY", nullable = false)
private String createdBy;

@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(name = "REQUEST_PAYLOAD", columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
private List<RequestPayload> requestPayload;

@Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
private LocalDateTime createdDate;

@Override
public Request createRequest(Request request) {
    LOG.info("Request to save request: {}", request);
    return requestRepository.save(request);
}
```

While persisting it's throwing exception as

```
could not serialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not serialize
```

It's failing beoz of

```
@Type(type = "jsonb")
@Column(name = "REQUEST_PAYLOAD", columnDefinition = "jsonb", nullable = false)
private List<RequestPayload> requestPayload;
```

if i change List to JsonNode then it works fine

Comment: I think you should open a ticket on the hibernate-types project from Vlad about this: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public class Request implements Serializable {
...
}
```

This issue is because the library cannot serialize the POJO to JSON